# PHP variable does not equal string in code but when printed is the string

Tags: php, mysql, string, variables

**SOLVED see below**

I want to check if a string is already in  my mysql database

```
function checkStatus($articlename)
{
    $articlename = mysql_real_escape_string($articlename);
    $query = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE '$articlename' LIMIT 1";
    echo $query;
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_fetch_array($result) !== false)
        return true;
    return false;
}

if (checkStatus($element[$i]) == true)
    echo $element[$i];
```

The element[$i] is not printed but when I copy the echoed $query into phpmyadmin I get a result.
Also when i just echo $element[$i] and copy/paste the value, lets say its Landskron Hell into the code to get

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'Landskron Hell' LIMIT 1";
```

then it also works. So the printed variable $element[$i] is the string ABC but in my code it isnt. To check this i tried

```
if ($element[$i] == 'Landskron Hell')
  echo "It worked!"
```

this also does not work even if echo $element[$i] shows Landskron Hell.

I'm really confused and would appreciate any help!

**TL:DR How can a PHP variable not equal the string it shows when echoed/printed?**

**Edit:** `var_dump($query)` gives `string(64) "SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'Landskron Hell' LIMIT 1"` and this exact query in phpmyadmin gives exactly 1 row as result!

**EDIT2:** thanks to `andrewsi` I added

```
$test = 'Landskron Hell';
var_dump($articlename);
var_dump($test);
```

it shows:

```
string(15) "Landskron Hell" string(14) "Landskron Hell"
```

so apparently there is a difference! But what is it???

**EDIT3** i converted the strings using `strToHex`

```
function strToHex($value, $prefix = '') {
$result = '';
$length = strlen($value);
for ( $n = 0; $n < $length; $n++ ) {
    $result .= $prefix . sprintf('%02x', ord($value[$n]));
}
return $result;
}
```

results are:

```
%4c%61%6e%64%73%6b%72%6f%6e%20%20%48%65%6c%6c
```

and

```
%4c%61%6e%64%73%6b%72%6f%6e%20%48%65%6c%6c
```

so apparently there are 2 whitespaces? in my element? but they are not printed?

**SOLVED!: I used `$articlename = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$articlename);` THANKS `andrewsi` who got me on the right track!**

Comment: try using `var_dump`, on both strings you want to compare. They will show you exactly what the variable is - perhaps there are trailing spaces in one? Also, if you're using LIKE, you might also want to add the `%` operator to your string - otherwise, you're doing an exact match, and you might as well use `=` in that case.

Comment: will try! I use `$element[$i] = utf8_decode(trim($element[$i]));` on the element before maybe there's the problem?

Comment: When you're debugging, `var_dump()` is one of your best friends. If your comparison isn't working - `var_dump()` both sides to see why they're not equal. If your query isn't working - `var_dump` it out to see what SQL you're generating, so you can run it directly in the database to see if it works then.

Comment: ok maybe i should add that my string contains a whitespace, maybe thats important. so it shows string(15) "Landskron Hell" to be precise

Comment: Can you try `var_dump($query)`, and add the result to your question? Does that _exact_ query work when you run it in the database?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Now - do you have a row in your database that has a name of `Landskron Hell`?

Comment: yes i have. thats basically what i did with echo. `var_dump` gives the same results

Comment: Ok. Time to debug further. What does `var_dump($result)` give you?

Comment: the results of `var_dump($result)` vary from `resource(8) of type (mysql result)` to `resource(46) of type (mysql result)` as i said its a loop so the function is called multiple times and each time the number increments from 8 to 46. But for `Landskron Hell` it shows 46 and this is definetly in my database

Comment: OK. I'm going to need to log off imminently but... If it's running in a loop, do you get errors every time, or just some of them?

Comment: thanks for your help so far! every time

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good function that returns false if it doesn't exist, the value if it does.

```
// For a simple query that should return a single value, this returns just that value (or FALSE) so you can process it immediately 
function db_result_single($result)
{ 
    return ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) && isset($row[0]) ? $row[0] : false; 
}
```

This is an example from [php.net](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array)

We can modify it so that it returns true if the value exists already:

```
function db_result_single($result)
{ 
    return ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) && isset($row[0]) ? true : false; 
}
```

Note that `mysql_fetch_row` is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 so it should be avoided.

Comment: All the `mysql_` functions are deprecated since `5.5.0`

Answer (score -1):

I noticed a similar problem. When I obtain a value from mysql database, and I compare it to another string of the same characters and value it show that they are two different strings. I can't understand why this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can search for similar questions, or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, ask a new question, and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)